# How to find files modified in last 24 hr but do not find from hidden directories and sum them

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, centos, find

I have following command to find files modified in last 24 hr and sum all of them.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /mnt/naspath -mtime 0 -print0 | du --files0-from=- -hc | tail -n1 >> /tmp/size.log
exit 0
```

However it does also sum the files form hidden directory under `.snapshot`

What i see in find man page is I can exclude `.snapshot` with following which I do not clearly understand.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name .snapshot -prune -o \( \! -name *~ -print0 \)
```

So now I hope to exclude hidden and sum modified file with following command but this is doing totally opposite. It exclude `.snapshot` but sum up rest of all. `-mtime 0` is not being effected.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /mnt/naspath -mtime 0  -name .snapshot -prune -o \( \! -name *~ -print0 \) | du --files0-from=- -hc | tail -n1 >> /tmp/size.log

exit0
```

Anybody please know how to correct the command.
Thanks

Comment: `find . -name .snapshot -prune -o \( -type f -mtime 0 -print0 \)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

You could write it in two ways:

1. Like [4ae1e1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944784/4ae1e1)s comment above

   ```
   find /mnt/naspath -name .snapshot -prune -o \( -type f -mtime 0 -print0 \)
   ```

   In words:

   > If name is '.snapshot' then prune, otherwise if type is file and modified in last 24 hrs, then `-print0`
2. Alternatively

   ```
   find /mnt/naspath \! \(-name .snapshot -prune\) -type f -mtime 0 -print0
   ```

   In words:

   > If not pruned (in case name was '.snapshot') and type is file and modified in last 24hrs, then `-print0`

### Analysis

Ok, to understand, what went wrong in your second attempt, lets have another look at it

```
find /mnt/naspath -mtime 0  -name .snapshot -prune -o \( \! -name *~ -print0 \)
```

First we expand this in the way it is interpreted by find (i.e. inserting implicit `-and`s and respecting operator precedence `(...)` > `\!` > `-and` > `-or`). This results in:

```
find /mnt/naspath \( \
        \( -mtime 0 -and -name .snapshot \) -and -prune \
    \) -or \( \
        \( \! -name *~ \) -and -print0 \
    \)
```

The `\`s are only for escaping. This is now easier to understand - in words:

> Any path matching `-mtime 0 -and -name .snapshot` will be pruned (i.e. skipped and not be descendet into, in case of a directory). For everything else which does not match `-name *~` do `-print0`.

Obiously this does not match with your intention, because you only want to prune paths named `.snapshot` *independent* of their time of modification. The main reason for this different result is the placement of the `-prune` command and the rules for operator precedence. Instead the filter `-mtime 0` should be applied for everything that was not pruned. Last but not least, the filter `\! -name *~` does not do anything you wanted, instead you would need an additional filter `-type f` to exclude directories from the final count.

### Note

**Note**: The expression `-name .snapshot -prune` should be the *first* expression to be executed.

For example `-type f \! \(-name .snapshot -prune\)` instead of `\! \(-name .snapshot -prune\) -type f` would lead to a different behaviour for non-files named `.snapshot`, like the directory in your case. As soon as `-type f` evaluates to false, find will stop evaluating the next expression (because it is *implicitly* linked with `-and`, which will never be true). The end result will be false in both cases, but prune will not be executed in the first case, which means sub-sequent descendance *into* '.snapshot' would not be prevented.

PS: I hope this explanation shed some light on your issue. Don't forget to vote, if you like this answer. :-)

Comment: So nicely explained.